# Removing Browser from Default Browser List

Tags: google-chrome, browser

So I downloaded a zip format of Brave browser recently and unzipped and using it , also made it my default browser through settings

Later i removed the unzipped files, But
its picking the older browser(brave) and not letting me update it.
[image]

Steps To Reproduce:

1. downloaded zip from here https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/releases
2. Unzip and Open the browser file and use it for while
3. In settings change the default browser to Brave.
4. Delete the Unzipped brave browser folder from PC.
5. Then in default Apps , you will see the blank browser as seen in the image.
6. Try re adding the brave browser. You wont be able to .

**NOTE**
I dont have admin privileges in my PC.

Comment: You say you have uninstalled it?

Comment: So, install it again.

Comment: (1) What happens when you select some othe web-browser in the Defaults list ? (2) Did you try executing firefox (eg) manually, then saying "yes" when it asks to be made the Default ?

Comment: Use: Control Panel, Default Associations, Associate a file type or protocol with a program.  Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention, i didnt install it, i downloaded the zip format, i have updated the question.

Comment: @manishkumar: Can you generate a .htm file association report using the [FileTypeDiag](https://www.google.com/search?q=FileTypeDiag) tool and upload/share the report to your OneDrive/G-drive?

Comment: @w32sh i dont know what you mean by that. But i think it can be easily reproduced.

Comment: I don't have admin privileges, i think cache cleanup is required, its picking the file location from somewhere and that needs to be deleted.

Comment: Ok. I can repro the issue on my computer. Open a Command Prompt and run this command-line:

 `reg query HKCU\Software\RegisteredApplications /f brave`

Pls post the output here.

Comment: @w32sh What is to be done next, Can you post the solution , I dont feel comfortable sharing some code i dont know the meaning of.